# Google free real-time stock quotes

Tags: stocks, quotes, real-time-quotes, google

With respect to: 
http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/01/real-time-quotes-for-free.html

My question is: Isn't this info freely available a.k.a. the ticker scrollbar as in:
http://www.dailyfinance.com/quotes/the-toronto-dominion-bank/td/nys

Which is continuously giving us stock updates, free.  What is Google adding to this?

Comment: Note that while Google offers free real-time stock prices, I believe their volume data is still 15 minutes delayed.

Answer (score 2):

Previously, Google had a delayed update for their stock prices (15 minutes I believe). That change enabled users of Google Finance to see updates to stock prices in real-time.